# Splitting row results

Tags: python, pandas

I have a list of words - That match a record in first column of the database. I use pandas to iterate through first column in the database and if word from the word list matches the word in the cell - whole row is extracted and put into a different list. This runs on a loop that goes through the whole list of words. I need the extracted row that gets appended to the new list to split the records from each cell using some kind of deliminator (white space, hyphen, or comma).

```py
import pandas as pd

excel_file = 'C:/Users/username/Desktop/Translation.xlsx'
translationFile = pd.read_excel(excel_file)

compList = ['HelloEng', 'HiEng']
newComp = []
length = len(compList)
for i in range(length):
    newComp.append(translationFile.loc[translationFile['English'] == compList[i]].to_string(index=False, header=False))
print (length)
print(newComp)
```

Current Result is:

```py
['HelloEng HelloSpa HelloIta HelloGer', 'HiEng HiSpa HiIta HiGer ']
```

I need the Result to be:

```py
['HelloEng(delimiter) HelloSpa(delimiter) HelloIta(delimiter) HelloGer', 'HiEng(delimiter) HiSpa(delimiter) HiIta(delimiter) HiGer ']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the functino `str.split()` it takes a string and split it by seprerator (default is `' '`)

If i got you wrong and you just want to change the space between the words into something else you can use the `str.replace(' ', '|')`

## Update

```
import pandas as pd

excel_file = 'C:/Users/username/Desktop/Translation.xlsx'
translationFile = pd.read_excel(excel_file)

compList = ['HelloEng', 'HiEng']
newComp = []
length = len(compList)
for i in range(length):
    result = translationFile.loc[translationFile['English'] == compList[i]].to_string(index=False, header=False)
    if result:
        newComp.extend(result.split())
print (length)
print(newComp)
```

Comment: I tried it, but unfortunately it throws an error (AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split')

Comment: @babis95 Updated it again :)

Comment: Thanks for helping me out. unfortunately another error (AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split')

Comment: @babis95 check result type, it should be string isn't it?

Comment: No. I still need the result to be a list as I would like to later access the values by index. newComp[0] = HelloEng,HelloSpa etc. and newComp[1] = HiEng,HiSpa etc.

Comment: @babis95 but the `result` varible, its a list? if so, its a list of one string?

Comment: OK - i see where i went wrong. I forgot to remove the 'split()' from the first time you proposed a fix... It works now. However its still not exactly what i needed. The loop should produce two strings - which are appended to newComp list. Originally they appended as two objects in a list with no deliminator between text - but remained as two objects. After adding split() the deliminator is there but the list now has more than two objects as each after a ',' is treated separately

Comment: Notice that i use the `extend` function and not the `append`, if you want it to stay a list as it is, change the `split` into `replace` and change the `extend` to `append`, if this is what you are searching for please mark my answer as correct :)

Comment: Working of your suggestion I managed to sort it. I just changed ```
 if result:
        newComp.extend(result.split(',')[::-1]) ```

Comment: yes that can work :) @babis95 please mark the answer as correct one :)